# How to avoid permission issues when using denon

Tags: javascript, deno

I was running denon, which is like nodemon in node, but I'm getting permission issues even when I've manually specified the relevant flags (specifically `--allow-net` flag.)

How do I run my app with denon so I don't have to keep restarting?

Comment: what errors do you get?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `denon.json` file in your project root.

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "start": "deno run --allow-env --allow-net server.ts"
    }
}
```

Then you can run the script this way (assuming denon installed):

```sh
denon start
```

https://deno.land/x/denon

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact error it's hard to give you the correct answer, but `denon` is unstable, it has several issues.

One of those errors that you might be affecting you is if you're trying to watch a folder that you may not have ownership you'll get:

```
error: Uncaught PermissionDenied: Permission denied (os error 13)
```

for example, if I run `denon` on `/tmp` I get that error thrown, even if the folder has all permissions.

Even though `nodemon` works perfectly on `/tmp`.

---

My recommendation is to use `nodemon` until `denon` is stable or until there's a better tool for `deno`.

You can do so by using `--exec` flag

```
nodemon --exec deno run --allow-net index.ts
```

For convenience you can use `nodemon.json` with the following content:

```
{
  "execMap": {
    "js": "deno run --allow-net",
    "ts": "deno run --allow-net"
  },
  "ext": "js,json,ts"
}
```

And now just use:  `nodemon index.ts`

Answer (score 0):

adding `--allow-net` solved it for me.

for some reason creating the `denon.json` file manually didn't work, so I had to run
`deno --init` and add `--allow-net` to the start cmd

```
   "start": {
      "cmd": "deno run --allow-net app.ts",
      "desc": "run my app.ts file"
    }
```