# drun is showing me error "not yet implemented"

Tags: deno

I am starting my Deno Server using drun Automatically restart server

`drun --entryPoint=./index.ts`

The server started at first run successfull but when i make any changes in deno code and save it  the result is as below

```
Compile file:///C:/Users/rajat/Desktop/demo/index.ts
Serving on http://0.0.0.0:3000/
Error: Not yet implemented
    at Object.kill ($deno$/ops/process.ts:8:11)
    at Process.kill ($deno$/process.ts:89:5)
    at Runner.run (https://deno.land/x/drun@v1.0.0/src/runner.ts:69:17)
    at async main (https://deno.land/x/drun@v1.0.0/drun.ts:11:3)
    at async https://deno.land/x/drun@v1.0.0/drun.ts:16:5
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant part of your code (index.ts code)? that would help addressing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`process.kill` is not implemented on Windows on your Deno version. A [PR](https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/5347) to support it was merged 4 days ago

Upgrade your Deno version to [`1.0.1`](https://github.com/denoland/deno/releases) which includes:

```
fix: Implement Deno.kill for windows (#5347)
```

Comment: I have Upgraded Deno to 1.0.1, Now i m facing many errors Here :** Property 'symlink' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'** . **https://deno.land/std@v0.51.0/fs/copy.ts** and  **https://deno.land/std@v0.51.0/fs/ensure_symlink.ts**

Comment: Use `--unstable` flag

Comment: while installing drun i have used this `deno install --allow-read --allow-run --unstable https://deno.land/x/drun@v1.0.0/drun.ts` and after running this command above error message

Comment: you need to use `--unstable` to run it, aside from installing.

Comment: `drun --unstable --entryPoint=./index.ts` i have used this to run index.ts even thought same problem

Comment: `drun` does not work on deno 1.0.1. https://github.com/MarcHanin/drun/issues/2

Comment: OK Fine, Think so deno 1.0.1 is in development mode, So Now i have Uninstalled it and reinstalled deno 1.0.0. Even thought i m facing above error " Not Yep Implemented".

Comment: don't use `drun`, use `nodemon`

Comment: My Code is compiled and the executing is successful but drun is not restarting server when i make any changed in code, when i hit save  it hows me " Not Yet implementeed" as have shown above

Comment: you're using a broken tool, `drun`, use a tested and fully functioning one like nodemon

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61869499/how-to-use-denon